# Can the word "facet" be used in a sentence like this one?

Tags: american-english

> - Leadership skills are also a valued **facet** in a friend.

Can facet be used in this way?

Comment: Why do you suspect *facet* may not be right here? Have you looked up a good dictionary for its meaning and usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you use the preposition "of" when talking about facets. And I've not seen it commonly being used when referring to persons. It's more commonly used when talking about inanimate objects or intangible ideas.

So a statement like "Decisiveness is an important facet of leadership" is perfectly natural and correct.

But "Leadership skills are also a valued facet of a friend" still sounds "off" to my ear.

Words like "trait" and "virtue" are preferred when talking about people.

Why not: "Leadership skills are also a valued trait of a friend".

Or: "Leadership skills are also a valued virtue of a friend"?

You can also substitute the preposition "in" for "of" in the latter two suggestions I gave.

Comment: Just to correct the grammar in my example, I just noticed that there is a mismatch of the singular and plural forms when I edited your original statement. My apologies. The first one should read: "Leadership skill is also a valued trait of a friend." and ditto for the other as well.

Comment: I think you are right, facets are for things and not people. I would include in your answer a translation of the original sentence to something that works a bit better – perhaps "Compassion is a valued facet of friendship"

Answer (score 2):

A facet is usually one aspect or 'face' of something. We usually talk about a facet ***of*** something. Probably because a *facet* of something is literally one 'face' of it, we don't about facets ***in*** things - think of a diamond with many facets. The facets are the flat surfaces or faces on the diamond.

We often talk about facets of jobs, problems and even people's characters, but we don't talk about people themselves having facets. Your sentence, nonetheless, sounds strangely correct as well as definitely wrong. I think this is because the word *facet* rhymes with the word *asset*, which would be perfect in your sentence:

> Leadership skills are also a valued asset in a friend.

*Valuable asset* is a very common collocation in English. *Asset*, as I'm sure you know, means a beneficial or useful thing. Here's the definition from Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> NOUN 1. 
>   A useful or valuable thing or person:
>
> - *quick reflexes were his chief assets*
> - *the school is an asset to the community*

In case you're interested in the etymology of *facet*, here is the entry from the Online Etymology Dictionary:

> facet (n.)
>   1620s, from French facette (12c., Old French facete), diminutive of face (see face (n.)). The diamond-cutting sense is the original one. Related: Faceted; facets.

Comment: +1 because with only 35 hits in Google Books, [*a valued facet*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+valued+facet%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is most definitely *not* "idiomatic", but [*a valued **asset***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+valued+asset%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) obviously is, with 27,600 hits (or even [*a valued **aspect***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+valued+aspect%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), with 3860 hits).

Comment: +1, though I have to say I find it somewhat odd to be talking about _assets_ in your friends. It sounds too impersonal somehow, probably because of its frequent use when talking about assets in employees.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree. I find it a bit odd to appreciate leadership skills in friends too!